# I can't seem to know how to concatenate two char pointer strings using strcat, is it not correct?

Tags: c, string, pointers, strcat

I can't concatenate two pointer strings using strcat, is it not possible?

I tried using them like strcat(s1,s2), and strcat(*s1,*s2), and all and it still doesn't work.

```
char *s1="Hello";
char *s2="Bye";
printf("%s\n",s1);
strcat(s1,s2);
printf("%s",s1);
```

When I run it prints the first "Hello" that is before the strcat, but the code doesn't display the remaining output and doesn't return 0.

Comment: `s1` and `s2` are string literals which resides in const memory location. Instead string literals you should have array of chars to concatenate two strings.

Answer (score 4):

Your approach cannot work, for several reasons:

```
char *s1="Hello";
```

s1 points to a read-only string (literal). You cannnot modify it.

```
strcat(s1,s2);
```

This cannot work because there is not enough room in s1 to add s2.

Use:

```
char s1[30]="Hello";
char *s2="Bye";

strcat(s1,s2);
```

With `char s1[30]="Hello";` the compiler allocates an array for 30 charactes and then copies the string "Hello" into that array. Unused elements are set to zero.

With `char *s2="Bye";` the compiler makes `s2` point to a read-only string, so to make that explicit it is better to write `const char *s2="Bye";`